# COBOL File input, numbers separated with space

Tags: cobol

I am a newbie of COBOL, I am facing the following problem.

I have a input file with content: 
2 3 2 4

4 numbers are in the same row and separated with exactly one space.
the 4 numbers can be in 1 digit, 2 digit and 3 digit

Can I put those 4 numbers to 4 variables with PIC? 
such as: `PIC XXX XXX XXX XXX` (This is not working.)

currently I am using substring to achieve the task, but this is not efficient and messy, is there any other way i can finish the task easily?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all your help, i think i found a way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by two ways. Number one is to use unstring sentence. Or you can declare a variable level 01 and define in it every variable of the string separately.

For example:

```
01 WS-FILE.
    05 WS-FIELD-01   PIC 9.
    05 FILLER        PIC X.
    05 WS-FIELD-02   PIC 9.
    05 FILLER        PIC X.
    05 WS-FIELD-03   PIC 9.
    05 FILLER        PIC X.
    05 WS-FIELD-04   PIC 9.
    05 FILLER        PIC X.
```

And when you read the file use:

```
READ FILE INTO WS-FILE.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an UNSTRING function (i dont know if you refer to that with substring)

```
  UNSTRING WS-FILE-RECORD DELIMITED BY SPACE
      INTO WS-FIELD1
           WS-FIELD2
           WS-FIELD3
           WS-FIELD4
  END-UNSTRING
```

with this if you have:

```
  WS-FILE-RECORD="1 2 3 4"
  WS-FIELD1 = "1"
  WS-FIELD2 = "2"
  WS-FIELD3 = "3"
  WS-FIELD4 = "4"
```

or if you have:

```
  WS-FILE-RECORD="1 22 333 4444"
  WS-FIELD1 = "1"
  WS-FIELD2 = "22"
  WS-FIELD3 = "333"
  WS-FIELD4 = "4444"
```

Answer (score 0):

```COBOL
01  YOUR-NUMBERS.
    03 YOUR-NUMBER                     PIC 9(04) OCCURS 4.

01  INDEX-YOUR-NUMBERS                 PIC 9(01).

01  YOUR-RECORD.
    03 YOUR-RECORD-4.
       05 YOUR-RECORD-4-NUM            PIC X(04).
       05 FILLER                       PIC X(01).
       05 YOUR-RECORD-4-REST.
          07 FILLER                    PIC X(09).
          07 YOUR-RECORD-4-END         PIC X(05).

    03 YOUR-RECORD-3                   REDEFINES YOUR-RECORD-4.
       05 YOUR-RECORD-3-NUM            PIC X(03).
       05 FILLER                       PIC X(01).
       05 YOUR-RECORD-3-REST.
          07 FILLER                    PIC X(11).
          07 YOUR-RECORD-3-END         PIC X(04).

    03 YOUR-RECORD-2                   REDEFINES YOUR-RECORD-4.
       05 YOUR-RECORD-2-NUM            PIC X(02).
       05 FILLER                       PIC X(01).
       05 YOUR-RECORD-2-REST.
          07 FILLER                    PIC X(13).
          07 YOUR-RECORD-2-END         PIC X(03).

    03 YOUR-RECORD-1                   REDEFINES YOUR-RECORD-4.
       05 YOUR-RECORD-1-NUM            PIC X(01).
       05 FILLER                       PIC X(01).
       05 YOUR-RECORD-1-REST.
          07 FILLER                    PIC X(15).
          07 YOUR-RECORD-1-END         PIC X(02).


    MOVE SPACES TO YOUR-RECORD.
    READ YOUR-RECORD.
    PERFORM 0100-FIND-NUMBERS
        VARYING INDEX-YOUR-NUMBERS
       FROM 1
         TO 4.

0100-FIND-NUMBERS.
    IF YOUR-RECORD-4-NUM IS NUMERIC
      MOVE YOUR-RECORD-4-NUM           TO YOUR-NUMBER(INDEX-YOUR-NUMBERS)
      MOVE YOUR-RECORD-4-REST          TO YOUR-RECORD-4
      MOVE SPACES                      TO YOUR-RECORD-4-END
    ELSE
      IF YOUR-RECORD-3-NUM IS NUMERIC
        MOVE YOUR-RECORD-3-NUM         TO YOUR-NUMBER(INDEX-YOUR-NUMBERS)
        MOVE YOUR-RECORD-3-REST        TO YOUR-RECORD-4
        MOVE SPACES                    TO YOUR-RECORD-3-END
      ELSE
        IF YOUR-RECORD-2-NUM IS NUMERIC
          MOVE YOUR-RECORD-2-NUM       TO YOUR-NUMBER(INDEX-YOUR-NUMBERS)
          MOVE YOUR-RECORD-2-REST      TO YOUR-RECORD-4
          MOVE SPACES                  TO YOUR-RECORD-2-END
        ELSE
          MOVE YOUR-RECORD-1-NUM       TO YOUR-NUMBER(INDEX-YOUR-NUMBERS)
          MOVE YOUR-RECORD-1-REST      TO YOUR-RECORD-4
          MOVE SPACES                  TO YOUR-RECORD-1-END.
```

Here's a way to do it. Maybe not a good way. Maybe not an efficient way. Maybe not an easy way. But certainly a way that doesn't involve `string/unstring` - using `PIC` only. ish.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a little state machine that ran through and calculated every number as it goes.  There are many advantages to approaching things on a character by character basis for parsing.  The code is usually very simple, especially with a simple regex like number or whitespace.

```
 Identification Division.                           
 Program-ID. PARSENUM.                              
 Data Division.                                     
 Working-Storage Section.                           
 01 II      comp-5 pic s9(8) value 0.               
 01 Num-Val comp-5 pic s9(8) value 0.               
 01 In-Str pic x(80).                               
 01 In-Ch  pic 9.                                   
 01 pic x(1).                                       
   88 In-Number     value 'N'.                      
   88 In-Whitespace value 'W'.                      

 Procedure Division.                                
*> Fake up some data...                             
     Move '1 212 303 44 5678 6 75 888 976' to In-Str
*> Parse Numbers                                     
     Set In-Whitespace to true                       
     Perform varying II from 1 by 1                  
       until II > Length of In-Str                   

       If In-Str (II:1) is numeric                   

         Move In-Str (II:1) to In-Ch                 
         Evaluate true                               

           when In-Whitespace                        
             Compute Num-Val = In-Ch                 
             Set In-Number to true                   

           when In-Number                            
             Compute Num-Val = (Num-Val * 10) + In-Ch

         End-Evaluate                                

       Else                                          

         If In-Number                         
           Display 'Found Number: ' Num-Val   
           Set In-Whitespace to true          
         End-If                               

       End-If                                 

     End-Perform                              

     Goback.
```

You should get output that looks like:

```
Found Number: +0000000001
Found Number: +0000000212
Found Number: +0000000303
Found Number: +0000000044
Found Number: +0000005678
Found Number: +0000000006
Found Number: +0000000075
Found Number: +0000000888
Found Number: +0000000976
```